# How do I pull a class name from (this) click event for api url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs that represent a city. I would like to be able to use event.currentTarget (this) to select an element and then use the class name to fill in an API fetch url. What is the best way to go about this? How do I capture this information to use down the line if not used in the same function?

this is what I am getting....

```
    jQuery.fn.init [div.city.seattle]
    0: div.city.seattle
    accessKey: ""
    align: ""
    assignedSlot: null
    attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
    attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: class, class: class, length: 1}
    autocapitalize: ""
    baseURI: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html"
    childElementCount: 0
    childNodes: NodeList [text]
    children: HTMLCollection []
    classList: DOMTokenList(2) ["city", "seattle", value: "city 
    seattle"]
    className: "city seattle"
    clientHeight: 0
    clientLeft: 0
    clientTop: 0
    clientWidth: 0
    contentEditable: "inherit"
    dataset: DOMStringMap {}

    function captureCitySelect() {
    $('.city').on('click', function(event) {
        const citySelection = $(this);
        console.log(citySelection);

        });
    }



  <div class="cities">
                <div class="city seattle">Seattle</div>
                <div class="city tacoma">Tacoma</div>
                <div class="city portTownsend">Port Townsend</div>
                <div class="city neahBay">Neah Bay</div>
            </div>
```

I would like to pull the city name class and insert into an API call down the line to search for that city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the classes with .attr('class') then tokenize them by space and get the second one "[1]":

```js
  $('.city').on('click', function(event) {
    const citySelection = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    console.log(citySelection);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cities">
    <div class="city seattle">Seattle</div>
    <div class="city tacoma">Tacoma</div>
    <div class="city portTownsend">Port Townsend</div>
    <div class="city neahBay">Neah Bay</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="city" data-city="seattle">Seattle</div>
```

Don't use a class.  Either use a data element and grab it with `data('city')` or grab the city with `.text()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
function captureCitySelect(param) {
    console.log(param);
}

<div class="cities">
            <div class="city seattle" onclick="captureCitySelect(this.innerText)">Seattle</div>
            <div class="city tacoma" onclick="captureCitySelect(this.innerText)">Tacoma</div>
            <div class="city portTownsend" onclick="captureCitySelect(this.innerText)">Port Townsend</div>
            <div class="city neahBay" onclick="captureCitySelect(this.innerText)">Neah Bay</div>
        </div>
```